# How to unnest Google Analytics custom dimension in Google Data Prep

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataprep

**Background story:** 
We use Google Analytics to track user behaviour on our website. The data is exported daily into Big Query. Our implementation is quite complex and we use a lot of custom dimensions.

**Requirements:** 
1. The data needs to be imported into our internal databases to enable better and more strategic insights.
2. The process needs to run without requiring human interaction

**The problem:** 
Google Analytics data needs to be in a flat format so that we can import it into our database.

**Question:** How can I unnest custom dimensions data using Google Data Prep?

**What it looks like?**

```
----------------
customDimensions
----------------
[{"index":10,"value":"56483799"},{"index":16,"value":"·|·"},{"index":17,"value":"N/A"}]
```

**What I need it to look like?**

```
----------------------------------------------------------
customDimension10 | customDimension16 | customDimension17
----------------------------------------------------------
56483799          | ·|·                | N/A
```

I know how to achieve this using a standard SQL query in Big Query interface but I really want to have a Google Data Prep flow that does it automatically.

Comment: By automatic do you mean a process that runs on some interval? Maybe you can use scheduled queries: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries

Comment: @ElliottBrossard Yes - I need it to run daily at a set time. A scheduled query seems like a possible solution so I will give it a try. Thank you for pointing it out. I was hoping to use Dataprep so that it is more reliable (scheduled queries are a feature in beta and could change or disappear) and easier to work with - nice interface and no need to write SQL and workaround for selecting the most recent table and setting a well-named destination table.

Answer (score 0):

Define the flat format and create it in BigQuery first.
You could

- create *one big table* and repeat several values using `CROSS JOIN`s on all the arrays in the table
- create *multiple tables* (per array) and use ids to connect them, e.g.

  - for session custom dimensions concatenate `fullvisitorid` / `visitstarttime`
  - for hits concatenate `fullvisitorid` / `visitstarttime` / `hitnumber`
  - for products concatenate `fullvisitorid` / `visitstarttime` / `hitnumber` / `productSku`

The second options is a bit more effort but you save storage because you're not repeating all the information for everything.

Comment: I would rather go with the first option and create one big table as this is the preferred way to import it into our database. The question still stands though - can that be achieved by using Google Cloud Dataprep? Thanks

Comment: I don't know - I would do it in BigQuery beforehand as it is usually much faster.